# Dynamically deserialize from JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have some JSON here. The problem is it doesn't match the classes data types anymore. My question is; is it possible to deserialize JSON Dynamically? i.e. if I have entirely different JSON's can I deserialize them into two entirely different classes without first knowing what class I want to deserialize each into.

Comment: Are the 2 types a subset of each other?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding another JSON type"? You mean adding another field?

Comment: For example .The first json type is like the one in the top. And the second one is totally different JSON type with different fields.

Comment: So two entirely different JSON's which would serialize into two entirely different classes? You say dynamically so do you not know what you want to serialize it into?

Comment: Exactly. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: Franctly if you just google your title or search in SO you will find the answer to your question immediately. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Answer (score 8):

You can deserialize dynamic object with using [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

like bellowing code piece.

```
 dynamic dynamicObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
 string name = dynamicObj.data.code;
```

But in my personal preference is using strong type. I think its more convenience.

you can use [quictype](https://app.quicktype.io/) for generating c# classes from JSON object

> quicktype generates strongly-typed models and serializers from JSON,
>   JSON Schema, and GraphQL queries, making it a breeze to work with JSON
>   type-safely in any programming language.

Hope the answer helps to you.